# PyCharm: Cannot navigate to step definitions

Tags: pycharm, cucumber, bdd, gherkin, python-behave

I am currently writing a test in PyCharm using Behave. The test in my feature file works properly but when I try to `command + click` the step definition it does not navigate to it. I have the Gherkin plugin installed and these packages. I also tried to install Cucumber+ but still no luck. Am I missing something? [image]

Comment: Are you using PyCharm Community Edition or Professional Edition?

Comment: Hi @ocos, I am using Community Edition

Comment: Someone using Community Edition also posted a question like this a few months ago. I tried one of my working Behave project with PyCharm CE and it can't also find the steps however there is no problem with Pro edition. Same for IntelliJ IDEA CE and Pro. I tend to think that Community Editions are not supporting `Gherkin` or it may be a `bug`.

Comment: Using BDD is a [PyCharm Professional feature only](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/bdd-frameworks.html). If you install 3rd party plugins you may get some functionality but clicking to definitions is likely not part of the plugin and you need PyCharm Professional for it to work.

Comment: @ocos, IntelliJ IDEA community edition  is definitely supporting Gherkin with Java - looks like it is feature of the PyCharm IDE that it cannot use ctrl+click in the community edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you describe is specific to the Professional version of Pycharm and is not available in the Community version. Check that point.